# GDB: stepping into a library

Tags: c++, debugging, gdb, segmentation-fault, systemc

Runnning my  application I get a Segmentation fault. I ran gdb to check where my code was failing but I get the following output:

```
Program received signal SIGSEGV, Segmentation fault.
0x39ca8000 in ?? ()
(gdb) bt
#0  0x39ca8000 in ?? ()
#1  0xb7d5df9a in sc_core::sc_port_base::complete_binding() () from /opt/systemc-2.2-rel/lib/libsystemc.so.2.2
#2  0xb7d5e104 in sc_core::sc_port_registry::complete_binding() () from /opt/systemc-2.2-rel/lib/libsystemc.so.2.2
#3  0xb7d5e13e in sc_core::sc_port_registry::elaboration_done() () from /opt/systemc-2.2-rel/lib/libsystemc.so.2.2
#4  0xb7dc669d in sc_core::sc_simcontext::elaborate() () from /opt/systemc-2.2-rel/lib/libsystemc.so.2.2
#5  0xb7dc8567 in sc_core::sc_simcontext::initialize(bool) () from /opt/systemc-2.2-rel/lib/libsystemc.so.2.2
#6  0xb7dc8b19 in sc_core::sc_simcontext::simulate(sc_core::sc_time const&) () from /opt/systemc-2.2-rel/lib/libsystemc.so.2.2
#7  0xb7dc9708 in sc_core::sc_start(sc_core::sc_time const&) () from /opt/systemc-2.2-rel/lib/libsystemc.so.2.2
#8  0x080555a8 in sc_core::sc_start (duration=40000, time_unit=sc_core::SC_MS) at /opt/systemc-2.2-rel/include/sysc/kernel/sc_simcontext.h:608
#9  0x08055119 in sc_main (argc=1, argv=0xbffff524) at module_pfn.cpp:49
#10 0xb7dbc698 in sc_elab_and_sim () from /opt/systemc-2.2-rel/lib/libsystemc.so.2.2
#11 0xb7d522e7 in main () from /opt/systemc-2.2-rel/lib/libsystemc.so.2.2
#12 0xb7a2e4d3 in __libc_start_main () from /lib/i386-linux-gnu/libc.so.6
#13 0x08054da1 in _start ()
```

As you can see, everything comes from a library, except the 'main' call and 'start',where I set breakpoints, but they fail immediately there. I mean:

```
#8  0x080555a8 in sc_core::sc_start (duration=40000, time_unit=sc_core::SC_MS) at /opt/systemc-2.2-rel/include/sysc/kernel/sc_simcontext.h:608
#9  0x08055119 in sc_main (argc=1, argv=0xbffff524) at module_pfn.cpp:49
...
(gdb) br /opt/systemc-2.2-rel/include/sysc/kernel/sc_simcontext.h:608
Breakpoint 2 at 0x8055584: file /opt/systemc-2.2-rel/include/sysc/kernel/sc_simcontext.h, line 608.
(gdb) r
Starting program: /home/guest/Solutions/eln/systemc-ams/module_pfn 
...
Breakpoint 2, sc_core::sc_start (duration=40000, time_unit=sc_core::SC_MS) at /opt/systemc-2.2-rel/include/sysc/kernel/sc_simcontext.h:608
608     sc_start( sc_time( duration, time_unit ) );
(gdb) s

Program received signal SIGSEGV, Segmentation fault.
0x39ca8000 in ?? ()
```

And we go back to the start.

I am not able to understand where this is failing. I see there is the name of the place in which this is failing: `sc_core::sc_port_base::complete_binding()` and I have access to the `cpp` where this function can be found, but only in the source files (not the library). The problem is that I would really like to go step by step through that code, is it possible?

Thanks :)

Comment: Debug build or an optimized build ??

Comment: note: the problem is *probably* in your code, not in the library.

Comment: @DumbCoder Probably optimized build. I will try if I can get a 'debug build'. This depends on the compilation right? Is there an option for that?

Comment: if you provide a invalid pointer to printf, it will crash inside printf. It is still your fault, not the one of the library.

Comment: Make sure that the library was compiled with debug info linked with the sources you have.

Comment: @KarolyHorvath Yes, I'm sure it is in my code, not in the library, I would like to know where and why it is failing, because it looks like it's pointing to some NULL pointer or something.

Comment: Ok. I will try with the library with debug info.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks guys!

I used a **library with debug info** and now I can go through the library code.